# Pass argument to constructor from Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, opengl-es

I have located error on line, when I start the intent (creating the intent is probably ok). This is the code, where I try to start the intent:

```
start.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent game = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PGame.class);
        PMainMenu.this.startActivity(game);
    }
});
```

and this is the class, which I start the intent to:

```
public class PGame extends GLSurfaceView {
    private PGameRenderer renderer;

    public PGame(Context context) {
        super(context);     
        renderer = new PGameRenderer();     
        this.setRenderer(renderer);     
    } 
}
```

I think the problem is, that I don't pass any argument to the context, but I'm not sure.

Thanks for any help.

#### EDIT 1:

When I remove everything else from the constructor so it looks like this:

```
public class PGame extends GLSurfaceView {
    private PGameRenderer renderer;

    public PGame(Context context) {
        super(context);     
        renderer = new PGameRenderer();     
        this.setRenderer(renderer);     
    } 
}
```

And it still crashes.

#### EDIT 2:

This is the error I catch every time:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{cz.vilix.planeometry/cz.vilix.planeometry.PGame}: java.lang.InstantiationException: cz.vilix.planeometry.PGame
```

Comment: What error did you catch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class `PGame` is not an Activity. You can only start an activity with an `Intent`. You need to create a class which extends Activity and set its content view to your custom SurfaceView

**Edit**

Dont forget to add Activity element in your manifest file. Like this example

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.yourApp.NewActivity" >
</activity>
```

Comment: The error was actually on my side, I have misplaced names of two classes, so it threw this error.
And I had it in my manifest, even it warned me that it's not an activity. Dumb me.